# Which are the operands in Lc3 instruction?

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, lc3

I read on [Wiki Opcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) that the operand of an Lc3 instruction is the data that the instruction acts on.

For this Lc3 instruction (from [Lc3 Instructions](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf))

[image]

Would the operands be both destination register and PCoffset9 or just destination register based off that definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*operands (who the computer is expected to do it to).*" - pg116

"*The LD instruction requires two operands.*" - pg180

The LD command requires both a register and a label. The label is technically a PCoffset9.

"*operands can be obtained from registers, from memory, or they may be literal*" - pg 180

- Introduction to computing systems, McGraw Hill.

So yes, everything after the opcode is an operand